# Does the word 'effortful' have negative, positive or neutral connotations?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What is the correct, common usage?

Can effortful be used in a complimentary way or does it more closely align with words like laboured that often, (but not always) have neutral or negative connotations.

Comment: It's not a common word, and has not developed any connotations beyond the literal meaning.

Comment: I think it is mostly used in technical/academic writing, with a purely literal meaning.

Answer (score 2):

It has a terrible connotation: that the writer is using a vague neologism instead of searching for a more specific synonym.

If you want to praise the subject for the amount of effort, use *diligent*. If you intend to highlight the difficulty of the task, use *laborious*.

If you are not the writer but the reader, find a better writer to read.

Comment: I agree with @Malvolio. Contrast "extreme lucidity and elegance of his style" with "the more effortful, but intensely earnest, prose" [1](http://cyberspacei.com/jesusi/inlight/art/elit.htm#_Toc505605180). Good writer's make reading a joy, not an activity requiring great effort.

Comment: More on word-choice: _extreme_ means on the edge, so what is his lucidity on the edge of? _elegance_ is an attribute of style so "elegance of style" is pleonastic. It should be just "his lucidity and elegance contrast markedly with the more laborious, but intensely earnest, prose".  I love "intensely earnest"...

Answer (score 0):

[A Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=effortful&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceffortful%3B%2Cc0) suggests the word has no common usage as it is fairly new in printed works. Use to the word  in contexts seem to indicate specific special uses, as in the very specific "Effortful Control" .
I would be very careful in using the word. Which is to say, I probably would not use it.

Comment: Oh ok, I came across it used negatively in literary criticism and it stuck in my mind as I don't think I've come across it before but I just searched the word again and it seems to be used mostly in psychology as a term for a particular phenomenon.

Comment: I'm glad you came to an effortful solution.

Comment: @Effortful In the context of literary criticism, it refers specifically to the difficulty of reading the book, so it's a negative. But it could conceivably be used in other contexts regarding an admirable amount of effort put into something.

Comment: It also has an overtone of suggesting a lack of success in spite of effort--a classroom "E for Effort".  (informal)